# Iterating over a CSV file within a TestNG DataProvider

Tags: java, collections, testng, testng-dataprovider

I'm a little confused as to how best to implement a simple DataProvider, having not done so before.

I have a very simple comma delimited .csv file:

```
978KAL,625JBH,876SSH,452GSH
```

I simply need to read it in and iterate over the records, running the same test for each record until done.

My code so far:

```
String csvFile = "src/test/resources/registrationsData.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";


    @DataProvider(name="getRegistrations")
    private Object[] getCSVTestData() {
        Object [] registrationsObject;
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                String [] registrations = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                System.out.println( registrations[0] + "," + registrations[1]);

            }

        } catch//File not found & IOException handling here
        registrationsObject = new Object[][]{registrations};
        return registrationsObject;
    }



    @Test(dataProvider = "getRegistrations")
    public void getRegistrations(String registration){

        Object[] objRegArray =  getCSVTestData();

        for(int i=0; objRegArray.length>i; i++){
        //run tests for every record in the array (csv file)
    }
 }
```

I know that I need to use an Object array return type for the Data Provider method.

I'm unclear as to how (and/or the best way) to retrieve each record from the objRegArray object.

This is a basic Collections question I guess; can anyone point me the right way?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/45231/11488).

Comment: @jonrsharpe my apologies, I wasn't sure where this post was best placed as I'm coming from a QA perspective

Comment: Given that you've accepted an answer here, you should probably just delete the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code with my explanation below:

```java
package click.webelement.testng;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OneLineCSV {

    final static String CSV_FILE = "/path_to_file/oneline.csv";
    final static String DELIMETER = ",";

    @DataProvider(name = "test")
    public Iterator<Object[]> testDP(){
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(CSV_FILE)).useDelimiter(DELIMETER);
            return new Iterator<Object[]>() {
                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    return scanner.hasNext();
                }
                @Override
                public Object[] next() {
                    return new Object[]{scanner.next()};
                }
            };
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "test")
    public void testOneLineCSV(String value){
        System.out.println(value);
    }

}
```

So I would use `Scanner` class hence it has the convenient facility to parse a string into tokens.

I would also use the capability to return `Iterator<Object[]>` in your data provider since `Scanner` is designed in that way. You simply wrap it with new Iterator that converts `String` that is returned by `Scanner.next()` to `new Object[]{scanner.next}`.

Using `Iterator` with `Scanner` is really more comfortable since you may not know how many values you will have to provide. So you shouldn't care of defining array size.

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to give example and explain so well